# Codeigniter + Joomla SEF (.htaccess) in the same server.

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, joomla, sef

I made a tab as a Facebook Application. This app was made over Codeigniter and it works really fine in my server but when I try to install it in another server, it doesn't work because Joomla is installed with SEF activated. Now, everytime I try to access

```
SERVER/ci_app/index.php/hello/world it always loads SERVER/ci_app/index.php
```

I wanted to edit the .htaccess but I didn't do it because the site is very visited and I don't want to mess up something.

The joomla portal is inside a folder lets say "/joomla" with an htaccess. I tried to made my own rule but I don't know if it would modify anything what is inside "/joomla".

```
RewriteEngine on  #This line is already written
RewriteRule ^ci_app/(.*) /ci_app/$1 #Is this ok?
```

Also, I tried every URI PROTOCOL in the config file without success. How can I make it work?
Is it possible to have both systems (Joomla-SEF and Codeigniter) together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you have two sub folders:
/joomla/  and
/ci_app/
If so the .htaccess file within the /joomla/ folder will have zero impact on requests to the /ci_app/ folder. I'd suggest you look at server config for your issue.

Perhaps I misunderstood and your folder structure is:
/joomla/ci_app/
If the latter then you can overrule the parent 'joomla' folder's .htaccess by creating a htaccess file of your own in the ci_app folder. Set the RewriteBase to the ci_app folder and all should be well.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 sub folders. SERVER/joomla, SERVER/ci_app. I thought the .htaccess inside /joomla would have an impact because the .htaccess in the root doesn't have any rule. As you suggest I would have to look at the server config.